# Spring Inject Collection From Superclass

Tags: spring, inheritance, collections, dependency-injection

I have the following scenario:

```
class Super{
    private List<String> someStringsThatWillBeDifferentForEveryInstancePerDerivedType;
}

@Component
class Derived1 extends Super{
    @Autowired
    private String name;
}

@Component
class Derived2 extends Super{
    @Autowired
    private Long configId;
}
```

I have a different `List` defined as Spring bean in xml for each derived class…call them `listForDerived1` and `listForDerived2`. **How can I wire these lists into my derived classes?** I attempted constructor injection but I can't seem to find any luck injecting both the collection and the other deps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use constructor injection with `@Qualifier`.

```
class Super {
    private List<String> someStrings;

    public Super(private List<String> someStrings) {
        this.someStrings = someStrings;
    }
}

@Component
class Derived1 extends Super {
    @Autowired
    public Derived1(@Qualifier("listForDerived1") List<String> listForDerived1, OtherBean bean) {
        super(listForDerived1);
    }
}

@Component
class Derived2 extends Super {
    @Autowired
    public Derived1(@Qualifier("listForDerived2") List<String> listForDerived1, OtherBean bean) {
        super(listForDerived2);
    }
}
```

Also see official Spring doc: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers

Comment: I swore I tried this and Spring looked for Strings that were on the context instead of the list that was on the context. I'll try again later.